# "Shouldn't have to "

Tags: expressions

"People shouldn't have to know that they are leaving digital footprints all over the place"

What does "shouldn't have to know" mean?   Does it mean that "they do not need to know"? or "they should not be obligated to know sth"?

Comment: The latter, "they should not be obligated to know".

Answer (score 1):

Between the two choices, *be obligated* is the most correct.  However, I think *need* is a more precise word.  The sentence is saying that people should not need to know this, that is, things should be done so that there would be no need for people to know, not that people might or might not need to know, but in either case they are not obligated to know.

Personally, I try to avoid this use of "have to" in writing.  There are more precise words and, as this example shows, *have to* is often ambiguous.